# How to run Rails/Capybara with Puma server in SSL mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, capybara, puma

I am trying to get capybara to run test puma server over ssl. Need help configuring it, please:

```
Capybara.register_server :ssl_puma do |app, port, host|
  require 'rack/handler/puma'
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, Host: host, Port: port, Threads: "0:1") do |server| 
    ctx = Puma::MiniSSL::Context.new
    ctx.key = ENV['SSL_KEY_PATH']
    ctx.cert = ENV['SSL_CERT_PATH']
    ctx.verify_mode = Puma::MiniSSL::VERIFY_NONE

    server.add_ssl_listener host, port, ctx # this line is wrong, but that's the gyst of what needs to happen
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent version of Capybara I believe you should be able to do something like

```
Capybara.server = :puma, { Host: "ssl://#{Capybara.server_host}?key=#{ENV['SSL_KEY_PATH']}&cert=#{ENV['SSL_CERT_PATH']" }
```

Comment: Didn't work, it starts puma and just hangs (capybara v3.0.3):

    `Capybara starting Puma...`
    `* Version 3.11.4 , codename: Love Song`
    `* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4`
    `* Listening on ssl://127.0.0.1:49691?key=/usr/local/ssl/localhost.key&cert=/usr/local/ssl/localhost.crt`

Comment: @Arman  From the output you can see that it is starting puma with SSL enabled - does it eventually raise an error (maybe after 1 minute) ?

Comment: @Arman Playing around with this - it definitely does launch Puma in SSL mode, but Capybaras check for the server starting only checks over http, so it's not going to work.  The only ways to currently make this work would be to let Capybara start your app without SSL , set up a separate SSL tunnel that directs to the app under test and then set `Capybara.app_host` to make connections default to the tunnel endpoint, or run the app separately with SSL and tell Capybara not to run it (and again set `app_host`).  The second of those options loses the ability for Capybara to monitor open requests.

Comment: @Arman You can give the `ssl_support` branch of Capybara a try - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/tree/ssl_support - and see if that works for you.  If you try it and it does/doesn't work for you please leave feedback in the PR - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/2028

Comment: Thank you. Tried it, didn't work, left a comment in PR.